# MYSQL Update Query randomly takes a long time

Tags: php, mysql, http, query-optimization

I have a php script on a webserver which is called ones per second.
This script accesses a mysql database and reads/updates some information. Most of the time the script returns the result in <30ms. Sometimes however, the scripts takes 4-8 seconds.

The table which is edited only has 1 row and 4 columns.

By recording the time different parts of the script use, i have found that the time is always consumed by the first UPDATE query. This is also the case if the order of the queries is changed.

I have also tried putting everything in one mySql transaction, then the commit function takes the time normaly used by the first UPDATE query.

I have checked for locked tables via "show open tables WHERE In_use > 0"; but none are found.

The code for the query which normaly takes the time is below:

```
// Add Timestamp
echo ("BeforeTimestamps Updated" . (time()- $time) . "Seconds"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
$time =  time();
// Try updating Timestamp
$sql = "UPDATE $LobbyID SET lastconnect=$reftime WHERE id = $PlayerID";
$conn -> query($sql);
echo ("Timestamps Updated" . (time()- $time) . "Seconds"); // DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG
```

So for some reason sometimes the first update query for a connection takes multiple seconds, and I have no idea why. So if anyone can help, I would be very happy.

Edit:
As Requested in the comments; here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| L2787828 | CREATE TABLE `L2787828` (
 `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `command` text NOT NULL,
 `lastconnect` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries- and note Taft this kind of query (where the name of the table is unknown) is frequently indicative of poor (and suboptimal) design

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table.

Comment: @RickJames I added the SHOW CREATE TABLE Output.

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies if I am jumping to the wrong conclusion.)

How many tables do you have?  `L2787828` makes me worry that you might have 2787828 tables!  That is a serious problem -- There is limited caching space for tables, opening (and the necessary closing) of lots and lots of tables would be very inefficient.  It is *much* more efficient to have all similar tables combined into a single table with an extra column to distinguish the rows as needed.

(It is quite OK to have a table with a single row, even a single column, but if it is not one of many similar tables.)

The timing would be explained by:

- Bump some other "open table" out of `table_open_cache`.
- Open `L2787828` -- This involves touching at least two files via the OS, plus some meta tables inside InnoDB.
- And then proceed with the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Unfortunatly I only have 1 table in the whole databse, the table name is just randomly generated. I am basicly trying to set up a Lobby system for a multiplayer game, where a Lobby with a random name is opened ones a player asks for it. But maybe a sql database is just not the best solution for this... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: If there is never more than one lobby, have a `lobby` table that does not go away?  In another direction...  "random" numbers are not guaranteed to never repeat.

Comment: @Whatever - Or, if there are many lobbies, but only one per player, then a `lobbies` table could have `player_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Well, there will be more lobbies at some point in time, when more players are playing. Right know i am just testing things, so there is only one lobby. I thought about making one table and then add a column for lobby id, I dont know if that will fix the problem though.